# when does vs when will to ask the future event

Tags: idiomatic-language

I want to ask when school will start.

I feel both of the following expressions are acceptable.

> When does his school start?
>
> When will his school start?

The school will start at the future time so the use of 'will' seems natural. But I feel the sentence with 'does' is fine also. I don't know why it's correct though.

What expression is more idiomatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can, and often do, use the present tense for future events that are, in the present, scheduled, planned, or expected, e.g.:

> When does your train leave?
> My vacation starts on the 3rd of
> September.
> The meeting is at 2PM tomorrow.

[The Present Simple Tense - Future Plans & Scheduled Events](https://www.esolcourses.com/content/grammar/presentsimple/presentsimpleg4.html)